# Reject, retract, revise, resubmit, rejected?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals

So, I rejected [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/87937?draftId=73971) ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBqf6.png)) because it contained incorrect information (`Math.LN10` isn't 2.718, it's 2.302). After that @Alex Filatov retracted, fixed this mistake, and [resubmitted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/87982) ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsWPb.png)) it. I wanted to approve this, but the site shows me I've rejected this (which I didn't).

Comment: I’ve had this happen to me too.

Comment: It sounds like it didn't remove the rejection votes when it was retracted and resubmitted.

Comment: As a workaround until this is fixed, I've been commenting on edits I think could be fixed by the editor, and giving them time before deciding to reject. (I too have had this happen.)

Comment: Heh, I thought it was a math documentation and became furious as to why it was here and not on Math.SE.

Comment: It effectively *is* math documentation, @bhargav. I cannot see a compelling reason why approximate values for mathematical constants should be included here. The whole point of having programmatic constants is that you do not need to know or worry about the values. If you really need to know (e.g., because you're deriving a formula?), then look them up in a mathematics text.

Comment: @CodyGray: It works as a quick sanity check that you have the right constant.  e.g. log2(10) vs. ln(10).  It's a way of saying "the well known constant that starts like this"